# concatenate strings and numbers

Tags: c++, string-concatenation

I am trying to read some images and to copy the information in a 3D buffer (a buffer of matrices  where the information in each matrix is the information from an image).  For opening the images with fopen, i need the name of the image (ex "pt_176118_x_0600_cand.pgm"). For reading multiple files , the number 0600 (start=600) will increase with a step =5 until it reaches 02400. So i need to concatenate "pt_176118_x_" , a number  and "_cand.pgm". My question is how to do this , more precisely, how to convert a number to string  and  then , after that, how to convert or represent this string so it can be recognized by fopen

although i've searched here for proper solution, none of them seem to fit this situation.
My code is :

```
FILE *ident;

for(k=0;k<360;k++)
         {     printf("\r Read slice: %d (real: %d)",k,start + step*k);
               num = start+step*k;
               sprintf(outString,"%s%d%s","pt_176118_x_%d",num,"_cand_test.pgm");

               if( ( ident = fopen(outString,"rb")) == NULL)
                {
               printf(" Error opening file %s \n",outString);
                   exit(1);
 }
}
```

Comment: did you try using to_string() function?

Comment: Why not simply `sprintf(outString,"pt_176118_x_%d_cand_test.pgm",num);`??

Comment: for this variant I get the error : Access violation writing location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::string` to build the string, and `std::to_string()` to convert from integer to string.

Note that `fopen()` expects a raw C string pointer: so, given the `std::string`, you can call its `c_str()` method and pass its return value to `fopen()`.

Sample compilable code for building the filename follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num = 600;
    string filename = "pt_176118_x_0";
    filename += to_string(num);
    filename += "_cand.pgm";

    cout << filename << endl;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

In a comment the OP noted that he's using the VS2008 C++ comepiler, which doesn't support C++11's `std::to_string()`.

In this case, `std::ostringstream` can be used as a pure C++ alternative (or C's `sprintf()` or `itoa()` can be used as well):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string BuildFilename(int num) {
    ostringstream os;
    os << "pt_176118_x_0" << num << "_cand.pgm";
    return os.str();
}

int main() {
    int num = 600;    
    cout << BuildFilename(num) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and when I try to compile the program, it gives me this error :   error C3861: 'to_string': identifier not found . I should mention that I have also included those libraries

Comment: std::to_string was introduced with c++11 and wouldn't be in VS2008 sadly.

Comment: Yes, you may want to mention that in the question. Anyway, I've updated my answer adding a C++98 example (not using std::to_string()).

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to use std::stringstream

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
FILE *ident;
const std::string prefix ("pt_176118_x_");
const std::string postfix ("_cand_test.pgm");

for(k=0;k<360;k++) {
  printf("\r Read slice: %d (real: %d)",k,start + step*k);
               num = start+step*k;

  std::stringstream outString;
  outString << prefix  <<  num << postfix; 
  const char* file_name = outString.Str ().c_str ()


  if( ( ident = fopen(file_name,"rb")) == NULL) {
               printf(" Error opening file %s \n",outString.Str ().c_str);
                   exit(1);
  }
}
```